# Flutter: Integration testing. Is it possible to visualize taps and scrolls?

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, integration-testing

As far as I can see, integration tests are good for running on a device and see how my program behaves.
The problem is that it runs too fast and I can't see anything.

I came up with solution to set `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));` in `setUpAll()` and after any significant action to at least see what is happenning on the screen.

Can I also see Driver taps and scrolls simulation somehow?

I tried to enter Developer Settings on my Emulator and turn on "Show taps" and "Pointer location", but it doesn't help. It shows only real taps by mouse cursor and not by FlutterDriver.

Comment: Maybe make a feature request